# Spyder can not find SciPy after being installed on mac 12.7.2

Tags: python, scipy, conda, spyder

I have installed Spyder on a MacOS using standalone installer, and
then installed scipy using conda.
When I run a python program that imports from scipy, the following error
message appears:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
  sys.prefix = '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64'
  sys.path = [
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64/lib/python39.zip',
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64/lib/python3.9',
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.14/x64/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Any idea of how to fix this problem? Programs that use numpy work just fine.

I looked at the PYTHONPATH manager. I don't know what PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH should be set to or how to set them.

Comment: The running Python doesn't look like that of a Conda environment. Conda only installs packages into Conda environments and doesn't (without hacking) expose its site-packages to other Python instances. Are you using `spyder-kernels`?

Comment: How do I tell if I'm using '''spyder-kernels'''?

Comment: It should be in `conda list` for the environment. Maybe have a look at the Spyder documentation, e.g., https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=kernels#using-packages-installer

Comment: conda list shows `spyder-kernels  2.4.4`

Comment: Have you directed Spyder to use that environment? E.g., https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=kernels#using-existing-environment